# How to set welcome message for messanger chat bot build using AWS Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, aws-lex, facebook-messages

I built a chat bot for my project using AWS Lex and then I integrated it with Facebook Messenger. After integrating with Facebook Messenger my chatbot interface looked like this.

[In the image you can see when some open the messenger he will get suggestions like "Where are you located?" or "What are your hours?" etc. by default.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Envg.png)

Expected output: I want instead of these default suggestions messenger should display customized message like "Hello welcome".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a customized greeting from your Page that will appear in Facebook messages and in the Messenger app for iPhone, iPad and Android when someone begins a conversation with your Page for the first time. Your Page's greeting will appear before any messages are sent.
To create a Messenger greeting:

1. Click Settings at the top of your Page.
2. Click Messaging in the left column.
3. Next to Show a Messenger greeting, click to select On.
4. Click Change, edit the greeting, then click Save.